# Magento 1.9 Fatal error Mage_Configurableswatches_Helper_Productimg' not found

Tags: php, image, magento-1.9, fatal-error, helper

I faced with a `Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Configurableswatches_Helper_Productimg' not found in /app/Mage.php on line 547` while **flushing the swatch image cache**.

Please let me know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Did you add any module? or create any modules for ProductImg?
If not; does the file ProductImg.php exists in  app/code/core/Mage/ConfigurableSwatches/Helper?

Comment: @Youri No have not install any modules and ProductImg files exist on the server

Comment: is it CE version? Have you tried to flush all caches?

Comment: @bxN5 yes its community edition and I have tried to flush all caches also.

Comment: please attach the content of the file

Answer (score 0):

create a file in Configurableswatches/Helper , Productimg like to :

```
class  Configurableswatches_Helper_Productimg extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

you can check in [magento helper](https://magenticians.com/create-helper-magento/)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell what is your Company Name or Namespace of your module.

For example `app/code/local/Foobar/Configurableswatches` would accept Foobar as **Namespace**, Configurableswatches as **Module name**.

This must match inside your `config.xml` file to be working.

```
<config>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <module_name>
         <class>Namespace_Configurableswatches_Helper_Productimg </class>
      </module_name>
    </helpers>
  </global>
</config>
```

In `Namespace/Configurableswatches/Helper`, create new file `Productimg.php` with this content

```
class Namespace_Configurableswatches_Helper_Productimg extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

Adapt your *Namespace* with yours.

Remember to refresh cache after.